# Pass id collections with check box tags and button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a checkbox to an element on a page and subsequently pass a collection of ids (if the check box is checked) on to a controller.

In my view I have...

```
<% @roles.each do |role| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag 'blah_ids[]', role.id -%>
        <%= h role.name -%>
      </li>
  <% end %>
```

...only with this submit button...

```
  <%= button_to 'Call Action', bulk_update_path('blah_ids[]'), method: :post %>
```

In my controller, I'm just calling a puts on the params like this...

```
  def bulk_update
    puts "Made it to controller; ids are: " + params.inspect
    redirect_to blah_path
  end
```

...and getting...

```
Made it to controller; ids are: {"authenticity_token"=>"0ptHDPrSW9sjRYmsoPb/WyuTQxiR60RzVom9h4HjdWo=", "controller"=>"blah", "action"=>"bulk_update", "format"=>"blah_ids[]"}
```

Notice `blah_ids[]` above is blank. I am expecting to see ids of the check boxes that were checked. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I didn't get your question. However I see that unspecified params in a collection path is considered as format or value of `params[:format]` as in your controller inspect params.

Comment: @Mayank I updated the question. Notice blah_ids[] above is blank. I am expecting to see ids of the check boxes that were checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I needed this wrapped in a form_tag in my view and use a generic submit_tag like so...

```
<%= form_tag bulk_update_path(method: :post) do %>  
  <% @roles.each do |role| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag 'blah_ids[]', role.id -%>
        <%= h role.name -%>
      </li>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag %> 
<% end %>
```